# trend of the csv data in pandas(python) by using matplotlib any improvement to the function?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Anaconda python

I want to find out the trend of the data by using `matplotlib` with **excel .csv** file,to find out the relationship of 2 data. Is this function enough for it?
[Example Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbxnd.png)

by comparing the slope of the trend to find out if the data are related to another data

the **CSV file** format like below:

```
     subject1 subject2 subjects ....
user1
user2
.
.
.
```

**Program**:
import library:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import requests
from io import BytesIO
import seaborn as sns

A = pd.read_csv("A.csv")
B = pd.read_csv("B.csv")
```

**Setup function**:

```
#trend(dataframe,color1,color2)
def trend(A,B,C):
    X = np.array([*range(0, A.size, 1)])
    x = np.asarray(np.reshape(X, (-1, A.shape[1])))
    y = np.asarray(A)
    plt.scatter(X,y,marker='.',c=B)
    x = x.flatten()
    y = y.flatten()
    m,c = np.polyfit(x,y,1)
    plt.plot(X,m*X+c,c=C)
    try:
        plt.legend(A.columns[0])
    except:
        print()
    plt.show()
    print("slope:",m)
```

**Using the function**:

```
trend(A.std().to_frame(),'r','g')
trend(B.std().to_frame(),'b','g')

trend(A.mean().to_frame(),'r','g')
trend(B.mean().to_frame(),'b','g')
```

Comment: Can you specify your problem more clearly? What output does your current function produce? What output do you expect or require? 
Try posting a small example dataframe, example of your current output and why it is not what you expect or want.
Also: small tip, if you're writing a function it's much easier to understand if you make the argument names meaningful, e.g. `dataframe` rather than `A`.

Comment: thanks I am new to this community,sorry for the unclear question ,I may edit it later